# jQuery selectable() function won't work in wordpress

Tags: jquery, javascript

I have this script in a wordpress website

```
<script>
  jQuery( function($) {
      jQuery( "#selectable" ).selectable();
  } );
 </script>
```

All my other scripts work but with this I got  TypeError: $(...).selectable is not a function(…). When I use it without wordpress it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always refer to to this [blogpost](https://digwp.com/2009/06/including-jquery-in-wordpress-the-right-way/) about how to including jQuery code in WordPress. It shows you how to use noConflict within your javascript-code.

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

    $j(function(){
        // YOUR CODE HERE
    }
}
```

Also make sure that the jQuery library is included on the frontside of your WordPress installation with the [wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)-function. Hope it will work out for you.

Comment: jQuery is loaded automatically. No need to enqueue it.

Comment: It worked for me. Tank you!